# Problems with footnotes in two columns

Tags: footnotes, ledmac

I have some problems the ledmac package. The footnote from \footnotemark in the figure shows up on top of the other, and is not included in the numbering (see pic below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %just some text graphics
\foottwocolX{A}
\let\footnote\footnoteA
\begin{document}

Text.\footnote{footnode1} More text.\footnote{footnode2}
Even more text.\footnote{footnode3} And more.\footnote{footnode4}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[]{image1}
\caption[]{Caption of picture.\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{footnote5}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Do anyone know how to fix this? It works fine in one column without the ledmac package, but I'd like footnotes in two columns to save some space in the footer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The updated version of `ledmac` is `reledmac`. You can specify column arrangement using the `\arrangementX` command:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\let\footnote\footnoteA
\begin{document}

Text.\footnote{footnode1} More text.\footnote{footnode2}
Even more text.\footnote{footnode3} And more.\footnote{footnode4}

\end{document}
```

## Non-`reledmac` alternative

If you only want multi-column footnotes, and aren't using other `reledmac` functionality, it might be simpler to use the [`dblfnote` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/dblfnote), which doesn't require rewriting the commands:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dblfnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[1]} \lipsum[1] 
Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[3]
Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2-4]} \lipsum[2]
Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
% \includegraphics[]{test}
\caption[]{Caption of picture.\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{footnote5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the update. However, this doesn't fix the problem. The \footnotemark from the figure is still in a separate location (and with it's own number)

Comment: That is occurring because `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` are not reledmac commands; you could rewrite them using the same technique with `\let\footnotemark\footnoteAmark \let\footnotetext\footnoteAtext`.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! Just what I was looking for :)

Comment: Is that actually working for you? It seemed to at first for me, but now I'm receiving an `Missing } inserted.` error. I added an alternative using `dblfnote` in case this is a bug.

Comment: It seems to be working, yeah. I have a few erros in my very large document, but not a "Missing } " one